# Returned JsonObject Null for only some GSON method calls

Tags: java, android, networking, gson, android-ion

EDITED MY QUESTION:

I've been working on my first ever programming and Android project.

In the following code I receive a:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.gson.JsonElement.toString()' on a null object reference
```

for trying to call a method on my **result** JSONOBJECT which was retrieved using a networking library: https://github.com/koush/ion and is being parsed using google GSON library.

A toast string message and a log.v reveals that the JSON object is being successfully passed with all the necessary elements included.(Or maybe not passed completely? The Log.v cuts off after some point.)

My confusion lies in the ability to call the toString() GSON method on **result** which leads to a successful toast message, while attempting to call any other GSON method like result.get(images_count).toString leads to my error. I tried to use if(result.isJsonNull()) before executing my code to make sure that result was not null, but even if result.isJsonNull() returns false my method calls returns the error.

**My 2 Part Question**

What is causing my returned JsonObject **result** to successfully execute some GSON library methods sucessfully(like toString()), while returning a NullPointer Exception for others as when I atttempt to reach a json element member through .get(string member)?

In the future, how could I place/recognize checkpoints where an object might return a NullPointerException? So far I only use Logging or Toasts to display current object/variable values.   THANKS ANSWERED BY BRONX.  I have to use breakpoints.

Code that results in the NullPointer Exception: (I have replaced my CLient-ID with xxxxxxx in order to keep it a secret from the internet).

```
 Future<JsonObject> loading;

    private void load() {
        // don't attempt to load more if a load is already in progress
        if (loading != null && !loading.isDone() && !loading.isCancelled())
            return;

        // load the tweets from album : gQxwy https://api.imgur.com/3/album/{id}
        //https://api.imgur.com/3/album/{id}/images
        String url = "https://api.imgur.com/3/album/gQxwy.json";

        // This request loads a URL as JsonObject and invokes
        // a callback on completion.
        loading = Ion.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .setHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID " + "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                .setLogging("ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING", Log.VERBOSE)
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {


                        // this is called back onto the ui thread, no Activity.runOnUiThread or Handler.post necessary.
                        if (e != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(Imgur.this, "Error loading tweets", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }

                        //Here i test if the object is Null.It goes directly to excute else, showing that the object is not Null.
                          if(result.isJsonNull()){
                              Toast.makeText(Imgur.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          }else {

                              Log.v("JSONOBJECT_STRING", result.toString());

                              Toast.makeText(Imgur.this, result.get("images_count").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                     }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Here is the LogCat which includes the successfully retrieved JSON Object(We can see the JSON Object in the Log.) The Json object DOES contain the element images_count. 
LogCat:

```
03-21 21:24:26.395    8035-8061/? D/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (353 ms) https://api.imgur.com/3/album/gQxwy.json: Connection successful
03-21 21:24:26.405    8035-8061/? D/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (363 ms) https://api.imgur.com/3/album/gQxwy.json: Recycling keep-alive socket
03-21 21:24:26.407    8035-8035/? V/JSONOBJECT_STRING﹕ {"data":{"id":"gQxwy","title":"playlist","description":null,"datetime":1425872636,"cover":"c7iJOmN","cover_width":160,"cover_height":120,"account_url":"JohnnyJem","account_id":18800283,"privacy":"public","layout":"blog","views":574,"link":"http://imgur.com/a/gQxwy","favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"images_count":10,"images":[{"id":"c7iJOmN","title":"Title","description":"Description","datetime":1425872636,"type":"image/gif","animated":true,"width":160,"height":120,"size":65008,"views":1175,"bandwidth":76384400,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"gifv":"http://i.imgur.com/c7iJOmN.gifv","webm":"http://i.imgur.com/c7iJOmN.webm","mp4":"http://i.imgur.com/c7iJOmN.mp4","link":"http://i.imgur.com/c7iJOmN.gif","looping":true},{"id":"SYRfZPy","title":"Title","description":"Description","datetime":1425872638,"type":"image/gif","animated":true,"width":160,"height":120,"size":139574,"views":1054,"bandwidth":147110996,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"gifv":"http://i.imgur.com/SYRfZPy.gifv","webm":"http://i.imgur.com/SYRfZPy.webm","mp4":"http://i.imgur.com/SYRfZPy.mp4","link":"http://i.imgur.com/SYRfZPy.gif","looping":true},{"id":"1aD2tdR","title":"Title","description":"Description","datetime":1425872639,"type":"image/gif","animated":true,"width":160,"height":120,"size":117092,"views":882,"bandwidth":103275144,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"gifv":"http://i.imgur.com/1aD2tdR.gifv","webm":"http://i.imgur.com/1aD2tdR.webm","mp4":"http://i.imgur.com/1aD2tdR.mp4","link":"http://i.imgur.com/1aD2tdR.gif","looping":true},{"id":"7UzUF79","title":"Title","description":"Description","datetime":1425872641,"type":"image/gif","animated":true,"width":160,"height":120,"size":146703,"views":785,"bandwidth":115161855,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"gifv":"http://i.imgur.com/7UzUF79.gifv","webm":"http://i.imgur.com/7UzUF79.webm","mp4":"http://i.imgur.com/7UzUF79.mp4","link":"http://i.imgur.com/7UzUF79.gif","looping":true},{"id":"3PKeSiW","title":"Title","description":"Description","datetime":1425872642,"type":"image/gif","animated":true,"width":160,"height":120,"size":136914,"views":753,"bandwidth":103096242,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"gifv":"http://i.imgur.com/3PKeSiW.gifv","webm":"http://i.imgur.com/3PKeSiW.webm","mp4":"http://i.imgur.com/3PKeSiW.mp4","link":"http://i.imgur.com/3PKeSiW.gif","looping":true},{"id":"o3UBVgR","title":"Title","description":"Description","datetime":1425872644,"type":"image/gif","animated":true,"width":160,"height":120,"size":129046,"views":483,"bandwidth":62329218,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"gifv":"http://i.imgur.com/o3UBVgR.gifv","webm":"http://i.imgur.com/o3UBVgR.webm","mp4":"http://i.imgur.com/o3UBVgR.mp4","link":"http://i.imgur.com/o3UBVgR.gif","looping":true},{"id":"qraDqOQ","title":"Title","description":"Description","datetime":1425872645,"type":"image/gif","animated":true,"width":160,"height":120,"size":93116,"views":466,"bandwidth":43392056,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"gifv":"http://i.imgur.com/qraDqOQ.gifv","webm":"http://i.imgur.com/qraDqOQ.webm","mp4":"http://i.imgur.com/qraDqOQ.mp4","link":"http://i.imgur.com/qraDqOQ.gif","looping":true},{"id":"K9PuB3S","title":"Title","description":"Description","datetime":1425872647,"type":"image/gif","animated":true,"width":160,"height":120,"size":84323,"views":481,"bandwidth":40559363,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":null,"gifv":"http://i.imgur.com/K9PuB3S.gifv","webm":"http://i.imgur.com/K9PuB3S.webm","mp4":"http://i.imgur.com/K9PuB3S.mp4","link":"http://i.imgur.com/K9PuB3S.gif","looping":true},{"id":"p3whCAz","title":"Title","descriptio

03-21 21:24:26.408    8035-8035/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-21 21:24:26.408    8035-8035/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.johnnymolina.nextphase, PID: 8035
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.gson.JsonElement.toString()' on a null object reference
            at com.johnnymolina.nextphase.activities.Imgur$2.onCompleted(Imgur.java:116)
            at com.johnnymolina.nextphase.activities.Imgur$2.onCompleted(Imgur.java:98)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java:107)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:141)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:128)
            at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder$1.run(IonRequestBuilder.java:246)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$RunnableWrapper.run(AsyncServer.java:57)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-21 21:24:26.411    6534-6864/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.johnnymolina.nextphase/.activities.Imgur
03-21 21:24:26.412    6534-6864/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.johnnymolina.nextphase/.activities.MainActivity
```

Ok looking at the logCat it seems that the entire JSon Object is not being printed out. Is this a limitation of what Log.v can print? Or am I getting a Null object reference because the network call isn't returning a fully complete object?

An example of what a Json object retreived from Imgur's Api looks like: https://api.imgur.com/models/album

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "lDRB2",
        "title": "Imgur Office",
        "description": null,
        "datetime": 1357856292,
        "cover": "24nLu",
        "account_url": "Alan",
        "account_id": 4,
        "privacy": "public",
        "layout": "blog",
        "views": 13780,
        "link": "http://alanbox.imgur.com/a/lDRB2",
        "images_count": 11,
        "images": [
            {
                "id": "24nLu",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "datetime": 1357856352,
                "type": "image/jpeg",
                "animated": false,
                "width": 2592,
                "height": 1944,
                "size": 855658,
                "views": 135772,
                "bandwidth": 116174397976,
                "link": "http://i.imgur.com/24nLu.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "Ziz25",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "datetime": 1357856394,
                "type": "image/jpeg",
                "animated": false,
                "width": 2592,
                "height": 1944,
                "size": 919391,
                "views": 135493,
                "bandwidth": 124571044763,
                "link": "http://i.imgur.com/Ziz25.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "9tzW6",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "datetime": 1357856385,
                "type": "image/jpeg",
                "animated": false,
                "width": 2592,
                "height": 1944,
                "size": 655028,
                "views": 135063,
                "bandwidth": 88470046764,
                "link": "http://i.imgur.com/9tzW6.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "dFg5u",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "datetime": 1357856378,
                "type": "image/jpeg",
                "animated": false,
                "width": 2592,
                "height": 1944,
                "size": 812738,
                "views": 134704,
                "bandwidth": 109479059552,
                "link": "http://i.imgur.com/dFg5u.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "oknLx",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "datetime": 1357856338,
                "type": "image/jpeg",
                "animated": false,
                "width": 1749,
                "height": 2332,
                "size": 717324,
                "views": 32938,
                "bandwidth": 23627217912,
                "link": "http://i.imgur.com/oknLx.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "OL6tC",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "datetime": 1357856321,
                "type": "image/jpeg",
                "animated": false,
                "width": 2592,
                "height": 1944,
                "size": 1443262,
                "views": 32346,
                "bandwidth": 46683752652,
                "link": "http://i.imgur.com/OL6tC.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "cJ9cm",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "datetime": 1357856330,
                "type": "image/jpeg",
                "animated": false,
                "width": 2592,
                "height": 1944,
                "size": 544702,
                "views": 31829,
                "bandwidth": 17337319958,
                "link": "http://i.imgur.com/cJ9cm.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "7BtPN",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "datetime": 1357856369,
                "type": "image/jpeg",
                "animated": false,
                "width": 2592,
                "height": 1944,
                "size": 844863,
                "views": 31257,
                "bandwidth": 26407882791,
                "link": "http://i.imgur.com/7BtPN.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "42ib8",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "datetime": 1357856424,
                "type": "image/jpeg",
                "animated": false,
                "width": 2592,
                "height": 1944,
                "size": 905073,
                "views": 30945,
                "bandwidth": 28007483985,
                "link": "http://i.imgur.com/42ib8.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "BbwIx",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "datetime": 1357856360,
                "type": "image/jpeg",
                "animated": false,
                "width": 1749,
                "height": 2332,
                "size": 662413,
                "views": 30107,
                "bandwidth": 19943268191,
                "link": "http://i.imgur.com/BbwIx.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": "x7b91",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "datetime": 1357856406,
                "type": "image/jpeg",
                "animated": false,
                "width": 1944,
                "height": 2592,
                "size": 618567,
                "views": 29259,
                "bandwidth": 18098651853,
                "link": "http://i.imgur.com/x7b91.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    "success": true,
    "status": 200
}
```

Comment: Try to do this, before the loop, to check the value:
`boolean o = result.get("images_count").isNumber()`. Probably, the is no `int` in `images_count`.

Comment: I can't seem to resolve the method .isNumber(); on result.  I only have the options isJsonArray , isJsonNull, isJsonObject, is JsonPrimitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can post an example of the json response we can help you better.
However from what i can see the JsonElement "images_count" doesn't exists, and so you get the NullPointerException.

From what i can see, if i try that calls from the browser i get this json response:

```
{"data":{"error":"Authentication required","request":"\/3\/album\/gQxwy.json","method":"GET"},"success":false,"status":401}
```

It is possibile that you don't add some query parameter request from the WebService.

P.S.: To display current object/variable values you need to use breakpoints and run your application in debug mode

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I posted the log containing the JSON object shown as a string. The reason you were not able to make a call from the browser is because you need a Authorization: Client-ID  "xxxxxxx" included in the header. My code is able to successfully connect though.  We can also see that "images_count" does exist in the JSon String output. Im just wondering why im able to call toString() on the returned JSonObject, but not any other method calls. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I figured it out. I was calling a .get(string ,member) to the json object which only has the outside parameters of "data" , "success" , and "status". I had to instead use the following:     JsonObject album = result.getAsJsonObject("data");
                            JsonArray images = album.getAsJsonArray("images");   In order to be able to finally access inner elements.     Thanks for your help!